# How python execute for loops in range()

Tags: python, for-loop

im a beginner in python and i just want ask how this code works:

```
for number in range(3):
    print("attempt", number + 1, (number + 1) * ".")
```

[image]

in this line's second argument number's value should change to 1 right?
then if i am going to add another 1 in the next argument and multiply the dot, shouldnt i get 2 dots at first loop? what is really happening in this code? (sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: `number + 1` does not change `number`.

Comment: `range` starts with 0 (unless you add the start parameter) and does not include the final number.

Comment: for number in range(3):
    dots = "." * (number + 1)
    print(f"attempt {number + 1} {dots}")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for number in range(3):
    print("attempt", number + 1, (number + 1) * ".")
```

range(3) means number gets values 0, 1 and 2
then inside print(), string "attempt" concatenated with number + 1 concatenated with string holding dot (".") multiplied by (number + 1)

the output will be

```
attempt 1 .
attempt 2 ..
attempt 3 ...
```

!! yes, you can multiply strings to numbers in python and it will repeat string number time

Answer (score 0):

The function "range" returns immutable objects, you cannot modify the values you get. Also, even if you could modify them, your code does not do it properly. If you want to increase the value of a variable called "number" you should either do `number = number + 1` or `number += 1`